# How to expand a specific node in TreeViewer(org.eclipse.jface)

Tags: eclipse, treeview, expand

I have a jFace treeViewer. I want to expand a particular node in that.And I kown there has a function ExpandToLevel(),but i do not know how to use it,this problem has disturbed me serveral days.

In addition, i am a Chinese student,so my English is poor,but i hope the question is clear.Thanks!

The code below,I do not know where is the problem,The tree did not expand at all.

```java
for (Object item :  ((ITreeContentProvider)fViewer.getContentProvider()).getElements(fViewer.getInput())) {
   for (Object contents : ((ITreeContentProvider) fViewer.getContentProvider()).getChildren(item)) {
                if (((ITreeContentProvider) fViewer.getContentProvider()).getChildren(contents) != null)
                    System.out.println("the content is :" +contents.toString());
                fViewer.expandToLevel(contents, AbstractTreeViewer.ALL_LEVELS);
        }
```

The code below is about the node model:

```java
package model;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LocalFileDir {
    private String name;
    private List children;
    private String path;
    public LocalFileDir(String path, String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.path = path;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPath(){
         return path;
    }
    public void setChildren(List children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public List getChildren() {
        File file = new File(path);
        System.out.println("获取当前文件夹********************"+path);
        File[] fs = file.listFiles();
        children = new ArrayList();
        if(fs != null){
        for(File f : fs){
            if(f.exists()){             
                children.add(new LocalFileDir(path+"/"+f.getName(),            f.getName()));
        }
    }
    }
    return children;
}

}
```

Comment: @NliuLin : Do you have a `ISelection` available when expanding ? or an ` `ExecutionEvent` ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'ISelection' and 'ExcutionEvent'?

Comment: At first, I get the tree,and then i search for the node i want to expand,next, i use the function ExpandToLevel().....

Comment: @flafoux can you say more detail?

Comment: @flafoux  I want the tree to be expanded when i open the shell.

Comment: @NIiuLin Have you got the solution for the above-mentioned issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
TreeItem[] treeItems = viewer.getTree().getItems();
    for (TreeItem treeItem : treeItems) {
        viewer.expandToLevel(treeItem.getData(), TreeViewer.ALL_LEVELS);
    }
```

Hope it solves your problem you can check the condition in foreach loop