# Select Node in TreeViewer

Tags: java, swt, jface

The lack of documentation for this really simple feature is disturbing. I have a `TreeViewer` and want to select a node. And the only way this makes sense is if the tree expands all elements up to the selection, else the user can't see it.

```
public class TreeWindow extends ApplicationWindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TreeWindow().open();
    }

    public TreeWindow() {
        super(null);
        setBlockOnOpen(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
        final TreeViewer treeViewer = new TreeViewer(parent);
        treeViewer.setContentProvider(new FileTreeContentProvider());
        treeViewer.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider() {
            @Override
            public String getText(Object element) {
                String result = ((File) element).getName();
                if (result.isEmpty()) {
                    result = ((File) element).getPath(); // root like C:\
                }
                return result;
            }
        });
        treeViewer.setInput(File.listRoots());

        // expand
        final File fileToExpand = new File("src");
        System.out.println("Expand to file: " + fileToExpand.getAbsolutePath());
        return treeViewer.getControl();
    }

    static class FileTreeContentProvider extends ArrayContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider {

        @Override
        public Object[] getChildren(Object parentElement) {
            return ((File) parentElement).listFiles();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getParent(Object element) {
            return ((File) element).getParentFile();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasChildren(Object element) {
            return ((File) element).isDirectory();
        }

    }
}
```

What I tried:

```
treeViewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(fileToExpand));
System.out.println("Selection: " + treeViewer.getSelection());
```

The selection doesn't get set. (I saw multiple times that `TreeViewer#setSelection(ISelection, boolean)` was used, but the JavaDoc states "Currently the reveal parameter is not honored because Tree does not provide an API to only select an item without scrolling it into view").

```
treeViewer.expandToLevel(fileToExpand, AbstractTreeViewer.ALL_LEVELS);
```

This method... does nothing?

```
final Tree tree = treeViewer.getTree();
final TreeItem[] items = tree.getSelection();
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
    final TreeItem item = items[i];
    TreeItem treeParent = item.getParentItem();
    while (treeParent != null) {
        treeParent.setExpanded(true);
        treeParent = treeParent.getParentItem();
    }
}
```

Might work maybe? But the selection does not get set, so...

```
treeViewer.expandAll();
```

This method normally works, but I don't think it's a good idea to try it in the above example. It does not do what I want, so it's a moot point anyways.

The problem seems to be that the `TreeItem` is created lazily. To check that you can try this:

```
for (final TreeItem item : this.treeViewer.getTree().getItems()) {
    System.out.println(item.getData() + " " + item.getItemCount());
}
```

This method outputs either 1 if the item has children or 0 if not, but **not** the actual item count. Also, if you try to get the children's data, it's `null`.

How do I select a node that is not expanded? How do I expand the tree to the selection / a specified node?

Possible duplicate: 
[How to expand a specific node in TreeViewer(org.eclipse.jface)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391944/how-to-expand-a-specific-node-in-treeviewerorg-eclipse-jface) (I'm not sure if this is the same problem, but there is no solution either way)

Comment: For `expandToLevel` try using a `TreePath` with the full path through the tree to the element rather than just the element.

Comment: @greg-449 But how would I get the path? This example has a `getParent(Object)` method, but it's perfectly valid (and as far as I can tell more common) to not have this method.

Comment: If you want to use expandToLevel with TreePath then you have to be able to work out path somehow. The problem with expandToLevel is that if a branch of the tree has never been expanded the viewer has no information about what is in that branch so just specifying the single element doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work on JFace 3.13.2:

```
// element is any object of your tree content provider data model,
// in your case a File.
treeViewer.expandToLevel(element, 0);
treeViewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(element));
```

The above code will make all the nodes down to the level of the selected element expanded, scroll the relevant part of the tree into view and mark the element as selected.

In my case the tree was four levels deep and the selected element was a leaf node. If you wanted to expand levels below the selected node, you can provide a level higher than 0 as second parameter to `expandToLevel`, or `TreeViewer.ALL_LEVELS` to expand all levels in the subtree.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I can't expand all the nodes in my use case: :(

Comment: @SteffiS., how can show the selected node if you don't expand all nodes above it? Unless parent nodes are expanded the selected node won't be visible...

Comment: Yes, the parent nodes of the selected node need to be expanded . Not the entire tree. (BTW. I have these methods in the question body, explaining why they won't work for me.)

Comment: how do I highlight the child node of a parent node?